# Need help for Spring transaction for Huge date manipulation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

please suggest me for this problem.

Am using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager as transaction manager for a service. And wrapped the code inside this transaction like this

```
TransactionStatus transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);

//DaoCalls

transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);
```

The Dao calls are operating lot of CRUD(Deletions,Updations,Insertions) operations on DB tables.

The problem is this tables are getting locked for longer time.
And All these Dao calls should be done in single transaction.

Can any one please suggest me for this problem.

Comment: Did you do a profiling to figure out on which call it's taking time? If you find the place, then you could think of solution. Otherwise there is no standard solution for these type of issues.

Answer (score 1):

I see only several options:

- **optimize** queries
- run some queries in **parallel** (use Executors from java.utils.concurrent), if you can
- depending on your requirements try to do **less locking** (e.g. **compensate** using read or write repair)

Comment: With multiple threads the process can no longer be transactional. Also I doubt CPU is the bottle-beck here.

Comment: Running things in parallel will not lower CPU utilization, it will be contrary, the goal is to save time here. I am not sure about the mutual exclusion of parallelism an transactions in this case - do you have an argument to support this statement ?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider writing a stored procedure on the database to carry out the complex operations.  That way you have far more control over the locking and queries that are being carried out and because the operations are happening on the database itself you don't have the overhead of moving data to and from hibernate.

Comment: Or else is there any way to set the tables are available for SELECT query even if the transaction is locked the table?